# Can Rhino Queues be used in-process?

Tags: rhino-servicebus

I need to implement persistent queues for a new solution and have been looking at Rhino Queues.  Unfortunately either there is not much documentation available or I am just not looking in the right spots.

Can I simply add the Rhino.Queues NuGet package to my project and make use of the queues in my application?  If so, where can I find better documentation that explains the proper use of the queues?  For instance, when running in-process, what do I specify for an endpoint?

Comment: Yeah, ["developer-friendly"](https://hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-service-bus) seems to be a bit of a misnomer in 2017 :P